# List of allowed characters from regular expression

Tags: regex

Does someone know about some way how to extract allowed characters from regular expression and construct user friendly message?

For example, by providing regular expression

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&amp;\-\+_\.\s]{1,10}$
```

to get something like

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 & - + _ . with spaces
```

I am using java. I can imagine that it could be too complicated or even impossible to cover all types of regular expressions, but maybe you know about some library, tool or algorithm that could help.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be by far easier and more user friendly if you simply provided what error string needs to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Not sure what are you suggesting. In case of invalid input I want to show error message to user saying something like: "Please enter only valid characters: [list of allowed characters]"

Comment: What I mean is that it will probably be easier to do something like: `if(!pattern.matches(userInput)) print("The text you have entered must contain a letter, number...` as opposed to automatically parsing a regular expression. I think that what you are after is overkill considering you just want to show a relatively simply message to the user. What will happen should the regular epxression become more complex?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done.

What you need is:

1. Turn your regexp body into a string.
2. Parse that string (with a regex for instance) that will output the desired list.
3. Apply possible regexp options (such as ignore case to the result).

This is tedious work if you're not VERY familiar with Regexp. I actually have code in production doing just that, but it's proprietary so I can't post it here and it's not in Java.

I guess you should first ask yourself whether there is no simpler solution for your problem. If for instance your regexp is a constant, you could associate it with a by-hand list of accepted characters.

Comment: Yes, that could work as all regular expressions are in the same format. I am currently maintaining list of messages associated with regexes, but it is growing more and more, therefore I try to find some more clever solution. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

If your input is a character-class like the one you provided, you could match it with the expression

```
([^\\]-[^\\]|\\.|[^^$[\]])
```

that will give you a list of elements like "a-z", "\+", "_" that you could then tidy up a little further, e.g., removing the "\", and then print it nicely formatted.
And you could extract the length information using

```
{([0-9]+)(,([0-9]+))?}
```

that accepts {1,10} as well as {10} with the "from" and "to" values being captured each in their own group.

That should get you started.

Comment: Yes, this is an idea I can start experimenting with. Thanks for the tips how to parse the expressions, you saved me some time.